# Django models architecture for full-text search in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, full-text-search

I'm building a web-site for a social interaction on a particular topic, based on threads, think of gmail, only public. There will also be some static info in vocabularies, as well as blog, how-tos, knowledge base, etc. It is django+postgres.

One of the most important requirements is a full-text search over all information, regardless of the type of a model. If the exact search phrase appears in the blog, and its twisted sister in messages, than a snippet from the blog entry should appear first in the search results and be followed by a snippet from the message. So, i need a table with all the texts indexed, and the links to _any_other_table_ in the db.

My first idea is to create a separate model with "loose reference", e.g.:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    obj_id= CharField() # An id of the object of a given model.
    model= CharField(choices=("Message", "BlogEntry", "HowTo", "EntityProfile",))
    content_type= CharField(choices=("subject", "body", "description", "tags",))
    body= TextField()
```

But it feels kind of wrong... This promises an unnecessary hassle around integrity of references when creating and re-linking instances.

So, the question is - is there any elegant solution that django would provide? What might be the most efficient architecture to solve the problem?

I am not asking for a direct answer, but rather a hint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/ ? Also don't use `CharFields` for object ids. In addition your `choices` is wrong, it must be a tuple of 2-tuples.

Comment: yeah yeah i know, just simplified it all. thanks for the hint, checking it out now!

Comment: I use SOLR for searching, text-charfields. [Solr](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/django_solr)

Answer (score 3):

I've had a lot of success working with [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1328/), which uses PostgreSQL's tsearch2.  I've tweaked it for various different purposes in various  different ways, but basically it works very well, and is very easy to implement.

Comment: that's a valuable info, thanks a lot! for the current project i have already set up haystack + elasticsearch, but will definitely use this snippet when appropriate!

Comment: Any such snippet for sqlite3? Please take a look at my [OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020797/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-sqlite3-database-in-django) and help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the hints!

while contenttypes is an ideal for this kind of task, it is really tempting to be DB independent

from what i've read so far, Solr is a reliable search engine, but i think, i'll go and try ElasticSearch via Haystack

thanks again!

Comment: I've used both Solr and ElasticSearch. I agree ElasticSearch is the way to go.