# How to use full-text search in sqlite3 database in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, full-text-search

I am working on a django application with sqlite3 database, that has a fixed database content. By fixed I mean the content of the db won't change over time. The model is something like this:

```
class QScript(models.Model):
    ch_no = models.IntegerField()
    v_no = models.IntegerField()
    v = models.TextField()
```

There are around 6500 records in the table. Given a text that may have some words missing, or some words misspelled, I need to determine its `ch_no` and `v_no`. For example, if there is a `v` field in db with text *"This is an example verse"*, a given text like *"This an egsample verse"* should give me the `ch_no` and `v_no` from db. This can be done using Full text search I believe.

#### My queries are:

1. can full-text search do this? My guess from what I have studied, it can, as said in [sqlite3 page](https://sqlite.org/fts3.html): *full-text searches is "what Google, Yahoo, and Bing do with documents placed on the World Wide Web"*. Cited in SO, I read [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) too, along with many others, but didn't find anything that *closely* matches my requirements.
2. **How to use FTS in django models?** I read [this](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/fulltext-search-sqlite-and-django-app/) but it didn't help. It seems too outdated. Read [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#search) that: *"...requires direct manipulation of the database to add the full-text index"*. Searching gives mostly MySQL related info, but I need to do it in sqlite3. So how to do that **direct manipulation** in sqlite3?

---

#### Edit:

Is my choice of sticking to sqlite3 correct? Or should I use something different (like haystack+elasticsearch as said by [Alex Morozov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35022138/3375713))? My db will not grow any larger, and I have studied that for small sized db, sqlite *is almost always* better (my situation matches the fourth [in sqlite's when to use checklist](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that while sqlite is an amazing piece of software, its full-text search capabilities are quite limited. Instead you could index your database using [Haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/) Django app with some backend like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch). Having this setup (and still being able to access your sqlite database) seems to me the most robust and flexible way in terms of FTS.

Elasticsearch has a [fuzzy search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html) based on the Levenshtein distance (in a nutshell, it would handle your "egsample" queries). So all you need is to make a right type of query:

```
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView
from haystack import indexes


class QScriptIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    v = indexes.CharField(document=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return QScript


class QScriptSearchForm(SearchForm):
    text_fuzzy = forms.CharField(required=False)    

    def search(self):        
        sqs = super(QScriptSearchForm, self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        text_fuzzy = self.cleaned_data.get('text_fuzzy')
        if text_fuzzy:
            sqs = sqs.filter(text__fuzzy=text_fuzzy)

        return sqs


class QScriptSearchView(SearchView):        
    form_class = QScriptSearchForm
```

Update: As long as [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) has the Levenshtein distance function, you could also leverage it as the Haystack backend as well as a standalone search engine. If you choose the second way, you'll have to implement a [custom query expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions), which is relatively easy if you're using a recent version of Django.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's just an advertisement for a different FTS solution, without any justification about what makes it better than SQLite for the OP or anyone else.

Comment: I have taken some quick looks into haystack. Do you know if haystack can accomplish what I have asked for in the question (the search part)?

Comment: Just one more thing. As I said in the question, my db will never grow and will contain just 1mb of unicode texts. Should I go for haystack+elasticsearch or should I switch to mysql and use its FTS, as FTS of sqlite3 doesn't have fuzzy search? Thanks in advance! Then I will finally mark yours as accepted `;-)`

Comment: Sure, you can switch, but I'd recommend PostgreSQL over Mysql, as long as it has the built-in Levenshtein function, and you'll only need to make a thin wrapper around it. Check out the updated question.

Comment: Actually what I meant is whether I should use any dbms that provides fuzzy search (may be mysql or postgresql, since sqlite3 doesn't have that), **OR** should I use hastack+elasticsearch, regarding the fact that *my db will not grow any larger*. I am expecting your suggestion as to which would be better option, regarding my scenario.

Comment: Please remember to tag me, or else I don't get a notification. For your last comment this is what happened, though your response was prompt.

Comment: @Shadowfax, sorry, I was pretty sure the post author was getting all the comments. More than that, until another person joins a conversation in comments, I'm unable to tag you, your name just doesn't show up.

Comment: FYI, I am the post author :) And yes, it did come to my notification this time. Please read the comment before the one about notification.

Comment: Sure, in fact I was speaking about post authors in general, but my English might have set me back ). The database growth isn't really a factor here. What matters is the flexibility you're expecting. Elasticsearch is designed specifically for search, so it has neat options, like custom stemmers, typos handling and so on. If your search engine is going to be a sophisticated one, I'd go with Elastic (and Haystack is just a convenient wrapper here). And if plain Levenshtein distance is enough for you - rdbms will do just fine. A story gets long, drop a line to inductor2000@mail.ru, if interested.

Comment: The link is old. New link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

Comment: This is a poor answer, which does not answer the question. SQLite has fantastic full-text support especially with FTS5 - it supports tokenizers, snippets/highlights, [bm25()](https://wikimedia-research.github.io/Discovery-Search-Test-BM25/), 'contentless' tables (which shrink down virtual tables significantly as there isn't a need to 'maintain' a separate index), and so on. To anyone reading this, do not resort to Haystack or ElasticSearch immediately. Not only could they be overkill solutions, but SQLite's FTS has covered significant grounds over the past years. Explore Django+SQLite further.

Answer (score 5):

[SQLite's FTS engine](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html) is based on tokens - keywords that the search engine tries to match.

A variety of tokenizers are available, but they are relatively simple. The "simple" tokenizer simply splits up each word and lowercases it: for example, in the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", the word "jumps" would match, but not "jump". The "porter" tokenizer is a bit more advanced, stripping the conjugations of words, so that "jumps" and "jumping" would match, but a typo like "jmups" would not.

In short, the SQLite FTS extension is fairly basic, and isn't meant to compete with, say, Google.

As for Django integration, I don't believe there is any. You will likely need to [use Django's interface for raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly), for both creating and querying the FTS table.

Comment: So in a nutshell, 1) sqlite's FTS can't accomplish what I need. 2) even if I [enable FTS in sqlite3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35011654/3375713) for my computer, I can't use django's ORM (like `QScript.objects.filter(v__search='egsample')`) to use FTS features. Am I right to conclude these?

If yes, what do you suggest I do? Thanks.

Comment: I write to confirm that you can use FTS with Django. But you will need to [use raw queries, or execute custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/). I personally gravitate towards the latter approach. With it you can use `django.db`'s `connections` and [routers to 'switch' between different SQLite databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/). This approach allows me to implement complex queries that interface between different SQLite databases, and is very useful.