# I want to built a multiple items search at a time like user can search for (rice, potato, eggs, etc) multiple items at once

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I am trying to split the whole search string by (, ) and then take each word to return each searched product. But that's not working.Can anyone give any idea on how should I approach this?

Comment: what you need is django full text search. check it out here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: @saviour123 Is there any way of using full text search in sqlite3?

Comment: yes. They call FTS3 extension.. check this resources.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020797/how-to-use-full-text-search-in-sqlite3-database-in-django, http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/fulltext-search-sqlite-and-django-app/